# Organizing templates in a django project

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to use the "app-specific" approach to organizing various django apps. For example:

```
- app2
    - __init__.py
    - urls.py
    - views.py
    - templates/
- app2
    - __init__.py
    - urls.py
    - views.py
    - templates/
- manage.py
- settings.py
- urls.py
```

One issue I'm having with this though is where to put the base templates that **everything**  inherits from? For example, at the top of all my templates I have `{% includes "base.html" %}`, but if I'm doing the above I don't see how I could do this in a logical fashion.

Comment: Is your `settings.py` really in the same directory as `manage.py`? That's an unusual project layout.

Comment: I'm not sure what "best practice" is, but I usually keep the base template(s) in a `templates` directory at project level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing first, You want "templates/appXXX/" for per-app templates (at least if you want to use "appXXX/template.html").

Second point: as you just found out, not all templates (and not all code FWIW) are strictly related to one given app. At one point you need to integrate your apps together to build a full website / webapp, and templates - specially the base template - are part of the project's "integration" layer. IOW: just create a `templates` directory in your project's root and put your base template there. That's what everyone expects anyway...

Answer (score 1):

This kind of question is sometimes closed as primarily-opinion-base; I'll give my two cents anyways, because I think it is a valid question.

The structure I use is the following (successfully employed in some Django projects that have less than 10 apps inside each project):

In the first image you can see that for this project I started every app name with the prefix `app_`, but that is just an internal convention. Note: the folder `.venv` contains the Python virtual environment, and that folder is not version controlled (the other folders are part of the `git` repo).

[image]

In the second image you can see that I have a folder `project_config` that contains settings, base urls, middleware, routers and other stuff. Note: Django docs usually name this folder the same as the project (which would be `tb_system_01` in this case), but I find the name `project_config` more meaningful for my use cases).

Then I usually use folders `project_config/static` and `project_config/templates` to store all the stuff that is common to the apps. Here also go my base templates, which would be my answer to the specific question you asked. The Django docs sometimes suggest using a top-level folder called `templates`, but for my use cases I found it more organized to have that folder inside of `project_config/`.

[image]

Comment: thanks for this thorough response, this is really helpful. Where then do you put your (1) credentials files (such as DB info, etc.) and (2) your manage.py file?

Comment: `manage.py` is in the project root folder (bottom of second image); credentials are usually inside a folder I call `local_files`, whose contents are not part of the git repo but copied manually into there.